# How can I convert get date to format of yyyymmdd?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, type-conversion

I need to convert `getdate()` to `yyyymmdd` format. Eventually I need to go back 3 years and ignore the orders older than 3 years.

I am not sure I converted `GETDATE()` to `yyyymmdd` correct or not.

This is what I did `DATEADD(YYYY,-3,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112 ) > D.REQUESDATE`

D.REQUESDATE is stored as Decimal. Should I convert it to String or Integer first.

What should my path to run this query?

The error is

"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

```
SELECT  
    MYCOLUMNS
      ,D.[EXPDATE]
     FROM MYTABLE
       JOIN TABLES
```

DATEADD(YYYY,-3,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112 ) > D.REQUESDATE

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have a syntax error so add your missing `)` to your dateadd function `AND DATEADD(YYYY,-3,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112 )) > D.REQUESDATE`

Comment: Is D.REQUESDATE stored as a string in the format of yyyymmdd?

Comment: D.REQUESDATE what is it date datatype\???

Comment: After I fixed the parenthesis that gives me an error of "Arithmetic overflow error converting the expression to data type datetime." The datatype for D.REQUESDATE is decimal.

Comment: what does REQUESDATE saves??

Comment: Why are you storing dates as decimals? You have some nasty conversion you are going to have to perform. Can you share some sample data so we know what we are dealing with?

Comment: @SeanLange that is what I am talking about why REQUESDATE stored as decimal??

Comment: "20181003" this is the format of REQUESDATE. Can you help me run the query somehow? Should I convert REQUESDATE to Integer or String?

Comment: It is stored in a decimal datatype but there are only integer values?

Comment: That is correct @SeanLange

Comment: 112 iis for yyyy-mm-dd not yyyymmdd watch it

Comment: 112 gives me "20181017" yyyymmdd @nikhilsugandh

Comment: interchane dateadd and convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure given the newly discovered requirements that something like this should work.

```
Convert(int, DATEADD(Year, -3, GETDATE()), 112) > D.REQUESDATE
```

Comment: You made my day!! Thank you @seanLange

Comment: its an up for me

Answer (score 0):

`DATEADD(Year, -3, GETDATE()) > D.REQUESTDATE`

You don't need to convert the date format to compare unless `REQUESTDATE` is not `date` or `datetime`.

`DATEADD(Year, -3, GETDATE()) > CAST(D.REQUESTDATE AS datetime)`

Comment: i think the point of the convert was to strip the time off from `getdate()`

Comment: Then you would use `DATEADD(Year, -3, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))`.  He is converting it to varchar.

Comment: I understand there are many ways to strip the time, just making you aware so you could include it in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the DATEADD() inside the CONVERT() not the other way around.   Otherwise DATEADD() will implicitly convert the datatype back to `datetime`.

The reason for the syntax error in your question is that you are missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
  and add_months(sysdate,-36)>D.REQUESDATE
```

sql server  equivalent:

```
DATEADD(year, -3, getdate())>D.REQUESDATE

DATEADD(yy, -3, getdate())>D.REQUESDATE

DATEADD(yyyy, -3, getdate())>D.REQUESDATE
```

Comment: That might be valid in some DBMS (maybe oracle??) but this is clearly tagged with sql server. And in sql server the add_months function doesn't exist and sysdate is not how you get the current datetime value.

Comment: @SeanLange its tagged sql

Comment: Ummm no. At the time you posted your answer the sql server tag was already added. All I am saying is this is probably the correct answer if they were using oracle, but since they are using sql server it isn't going to work for them.

Comment: I am using SSMS. This doesnt work because datatypes are not same @nikhilsugandh

Answer (score 0):

Your existing query can work. You are only getting the error because you're missing a closing parenthesis, try...

```
AND DATEADD(YYYY,-3,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112 )) > D.REQUESDATE
```